# server error 500 when running a project (after upgrading windows)

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows

i updated windows 10 on which previously i had vs 2015 preview and now running a project gives an error.

> System.TypeLoadException Could not load type
>   'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' from assembly 'System.Runtime,
>   Version=4.0.20.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

this is the full error: http://pastie.org/private/b97yxhfwxoa8hmlwmoqg

i managed to figure out that for some reason asp.net got uninstalled :( so have installed it from the add features, but still doesn't work.

i also tried the `kvm upgrade` but that didn't help as well. so what i should do to make the project workable / runnable again?

Comment: am I to deduce from the downvote that the question is not welcome here? ;)

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that the VS2015 has a different version of the .net runtime and therefore the version numbers will be different, likely lower.

In this case, you will not be able to perform an assembly redirect.

I would suggest editing the project and re-adding the references to this namespace and that might solve the issue. It might mean doing the same process for others.

Comment: thnx. any example? as I don't really get what I should do. close/reopen project? remove references and re-add them from the references node? or something else?